# Removing text with links with JavaScript, new at this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, click

How do I allow the X inside the "li" tags to be the only clickable part of the text, but still delete the whole line? Thank you in advance. This is my third day working with JS.

```
    $("button#hello").click(function() {
    $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Hi X</li>");
    $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Hello X</li>");

        $("ul#user").children("li").first().click(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $("ul#webpage").children("li").first().click(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
   });
```

Comment: Wrap the X in a tag, and use `parent()` to delete the `li` element when the X is clicked.

Comment: I wrapped the Xs in a <div> tag and replaced .children("li") with .parent("div"). Now it's deleting everything up to the <ul> tags.

Comment: Why did you use `parent('div')`? See here on how to use it https://api.jquery.com/parent/, and why that didn't work.

Comment: Do you have elements in your HTML that have the class of hello, user and web page? You don't need $('ul#user') you could do something like $('#user ul').prepend() to prepend an element into user's ul paste your code with HTML to http://www.jsbin.com and I can help you its hard to tell what you're taking about though with this little of information

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("button#hello").click(function() {
    var x = $('<span>X</span>').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    $("<li>Hi </li>").append(x).prependTo("ul#user");
    $("<li>Hello </li>").append(x.clone(true)).prependTo("ul#webpage");
});
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KHUbf/1/

Comment: Woo! It works. What tools do you use for JavaScript debugging?

Comment: For debugging Javascript you can use the Developer Tools that come with all the major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE10), or Firebug (for Firefox only). I suggest you follow some tutorials about these tools if you are not familiar with them, as you will need to use them a lot in your development work. Just pick the one for your favourite browser and use Google to find tutorials, you will find plenty of them.